# Set a default view in Ionic AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have started learning Ionic. I am tying to set a default route to my **home.html** but it is not working.

**index.html**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button icon ion-navicon"></button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title" style="text-align: center;">Title!</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button icon ion-home"></button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'login': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the url of home

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          'login': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```